# Pybluez installation in Linux

Tags: python, linux, failed-installation

I am trying to install PyBluez-0.18 on my Linux Mint 15 machine, but got an error message during the installation process. I tried searching online to see if others might have encountered this problem, but I could not find any.

I list the command I tried to execute, along with the error message I received. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong, and what I need to do to reso

```
tri108354@prtgc004-Latitude-E6320 ~/Downloads/PyBluez-0.18 $ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'bluetooth._bluetooth' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/tri108354/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c bluez/btmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/bluez/btmodule.o
In file included from bluez/btmodule.c:20:0:
bluez/btmodule.h:5:33: fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to install libbluetooth-dev package for compiling your code

```
sudo apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

That should install the bluetooth header files.